# SharePoint Online C#/CSOM configure the list form

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, modern-experience, json-formatting

Is there any way via C#/CSOM to set custom JSON formatters for form, I mean the [Configure the list form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using SharePoint CSOM version `16.1.19814.12000` or higher.

You need to update the **ClientFormCustomFormatter** property of content type.

```
public property Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentType.ClientFormCustomFormatter
```

This property is introduced in version `16.1.19814.12000` > [New SharePoint CSOM version released for SharePoint Online – February 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-sharepoint-online-february-2020/)

**Sample JSON**:

```
ClientFormCustomFormatter: {
  "headerJSONFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "Custom Header",
  },
  "bodyJSONFormatter": {
    "sections": [
      {
        "displayname": "Title Section",
        "fields": [
          "Title"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "footerJSONFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "Custom Footer",
  }
}
```

**Additional References**:

1. [What is ClientFormCustomFormatter?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286145/what-is-clientformcustomformatter)